# Swordsage feat selection to amplify his battle prowess?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

The following question was raised during the making of a strength based, two handing (a little bit MAD) swordsage.

Currently my feat selection is based on the *Master of the Nine* prerequisites (them being Improved Initiative, Improved Unarmed Strike, Dodge, Blindfight and Adaptive Style) and Superior Unarmed Damage. I have two empty slots (being human) to fill with something that will enhance my to attack or damage. Any one has something good, combo or not, in mind?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you check out @BrianBallsun-Stanton answer to [Is master of the nine a solid prestige class for a swordsage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12487/is-master-of-the-nine-a-solid-prestige-class-for-a-swordsage) you should be able to find what you are looking for.

If not I've also located the following discussions:

- [Build a Sword Sage](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=36318) *Weapon Finesse, Shadowblade (counters the twf penalties)*
- [Swordsage builds](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=235242#post12844833) *Improved Trip and Combat Reflexes*
- [Halfling Vampire SwordSage](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Halfling_Vampire_SwordSage) (Yes it is silly, but fodder for the prepared mind.)

  > Weapon Finesse, Shadow Blade (add dex to dmg), Superior Unarmed Strike (OP fist dmg), Fanged Lunge (Allows you to drain victims with unarmed attacks), Leadership, Improved Initiative, Sudden Recovery (recover maneuver as a swift action)
- [Balance & Build Advice on Swordsage](http://www.enworld.org/forum/d-d-legacy-discussion/312364-3-5-tome-battle-need-balance-build-advice-swordsage.html) *Adaptive Style*

Comment: I think this has the makings of a good answer, could you expand on the links, perhaps with relevant quotes? As it stands now this answer would not be of much use if any of those links broke.